# how to add / remove values in a drop down list using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a 2 drop down lists with that same values and the values are populated by database values. The problem I am trying to solve is that the 2 drop down boxes cannot have the same value when the form is submitted. The POST values must be different.

If the user selects option A from dropdown box A, I would like to remove option A from drop downdrop box B. If the user then selects option B from dropdown box A, I would like option A to be put back in dropdown box B and the new value option B to be removed from dropdown box B.

I have tried a couple of different ways to do this, the closest being the following code.
This bit does what I want when the page loads.....

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.dropdownAcache = { 
        val : "",
        val1 : "",
    };

    $('#id_A').ready(function() {
        var optionval = $('#id_A').val();
        $.dropdownAcache.val = $('#id_A').val();
        $('#id_B > option[value=' + optionval + ']').remove();
    });

    $('#id_A').click(function() {
        var optionval = $('#id_A').val();
        $.dropdownAcache.val1 = $('#id_A').val();
        $('#id_B > option[value=' + optionval + ']').remove();
        $('#id_B').append$(dropdownAcache.val);
        $.dropdownAcache.val = $.dropdownAcache.val1;
    });
```

.... but all it seems to do is remove the values from dropdown box B but never adds the values back in. It's actually quite comical as I end up with no values in dropdown box B, but in all seriousness can anyone help to get this working?

Cheers - Oli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event you should be using is the 'change' event. Also, you don't need the second `.ready()` callback, it serves no purpose (the first `.ready()` handles that)

```
$.dropdownAcache = { 
    val : "",
    val1 : ""
};

$(document).ready(function() {

    var optionval = $('#id_A').val();
    $.dropdownAcache.val = $('#id_A').val();
    $('#id_B > option[value="' + optionval + '"]').remove();

    $('#id_A').change(function() {
        optionval = $('#id_A').val();
        $.dropdownAcache.val1 = optionval;
        $('#id_B > option[value="' + optionval + '"]').remove();
        $('#id_B').append( $.dropdownAcache.val );
        $.dropdownAcache.val = $.dropdownAcache.val1;
    });
});
```

(As for why your list never gets the values added back, you have an unfortunately placed typo `.append$(dropdownAcache.val);`)

Comment: I've appended the code as you suggested and it's still not working. Cleared my browser cache etc. Is the theory correct here? Ie using a global variable to store the previous value? Thanks..

Comment: Why `$.dropdownAcache` and not just `dropdownAcache`?

Comment: hmm - I have done this and the values still do not get appended to the dropdown box.. I'll keep playing but is the logic correct here? Ie the use of global variables to cache the value and then append the value back in to the drop down box?

Comment: I have change the $.dropdownAcache to just dropdownAcache as suggested. I am getting somewhere - if i add the following, $('#id_B').append( new Option (dropdowncache.val ) ); it adds in a value now, but the ID of the field and not the value

Comment: This answer got me on my way. I had to use optionval = $('#id_A option:selected').text(); to get the text value selected I had to use $('#id_B').append( new Option (dropdowncache.val ) ); - @nbrooks -thanks for your help,

Comment: I wasn't suggesting changing $.dropdownAcache, I was asking nbrooks what the purpose of the $. prefix is.

Comment: @Barmar No special purpose except providing a namespace for the variable; people sometime use the jQuery object for keeping track of lots of different functions or properties in one spot. I simply reused it from the original post though, `var dropdownAcache` works fine too.